# jquery, javascript: проверка валидности файла по пути

Tags: javascript, jquery, файлы, path

Подскажите как на клиенте (браузере) с помощью jquery/javascript проверить, что файл (изображение) по имени `$my_path` существует.

При этом хочется, чтобы способ работал быстро (т.е. без создания изображения, загрузки по `src` изображения и отслеживания `onerror`).

Comment: Никак. В браузере уже нет никакого пути, есть только http-запросы и что бы узнать наличие файла нужно сделать запрос, т.е. таки загрузить картинку.

Comment: Alexey, т.е. мне сформировать ajax запрос, отправить на сервер, а сервер уже сам с помощью php проверит и ответит?